# Does Aptana Studio 3.6.1 really need Node.js? Why?

Tags: node.js, windows, aptana, aptana3

The interactive install for Aptana Studio 3.6.1 insists on downloading and installing (a somewhat out of date version of) Node.js.

However, if you do a passive installation, it doesn't bother - and Aptana Studio seems to work perfectly well anyway.  Similarly, if you do an interactive installation and then uninstall Node.js, Aptana Studio keeps running, or at least fails to collapse in an *immediate* screaming heap.

I don't see the connection between Aptana Studio and Node.js to begin with.  Is it really necessary?  If so, why?

*Context:*

I'm installing Aptana Studio in a teaching lab at my University.  While installing Node.js first isn't a problem per se, it does mean an additional piece of software to keep track of, and interdependencies between software products can be a pain - e.g., if Aptana Studio is no longer needed, does that mean I can remove Node.js, or has someone started using it for other purposes and forgotten to warn me?  Plus, Node.js does some weird things, e.g., adding a folder that doesn't exist to the user's path.

In short, if I can be reasonably sure that leaving it out won't break anything important, it would be preferable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having run Aptana Studio 3.6.1 without Node.js for a full semester with no (new) problems reported, I conclude that Aptana Studio does *not* really need Node.js.

Comment: Aptana probably use node to parse and debug javascript code. So if you don't do javascript development (either in browser or node) or if you do browser based javascript development but don't plan on using Aptana as a debugger or don't care much about javascript intellisense then you don't need node.